# No "www" in front of our URL in Google listing?

Tags: google-search

Basically our website is listed in Google but the URL only has "ourdomain.com" whereas we'd like it to properly have "www.ourdomain.com".

Is there a way to inform the Google spiders of this? A meta tag? A setting in our httpd? Or is it a DNS host setting we'll need to contact our hosting provider about?

Comment: did yo finally get an answer to your question? could you indicate which worked? cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can actually be controlled from Google's webmaster tools. You'll have to go through the site verification process first, but once it's set up, you can apply your preference for how the domain displays in search result listings.

Answer (score 0):

You should setup a 301 Permanent Redirect that points to your www. address. This can be done by adding the following to your .htaccess file.

```
## Redirect to www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That way when Google next indexes your site, their bots should pick up this redirect and update their listings.

Answer (score 0):

Using **[Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/)** to tell Google your preference (you will need to create a Google Account if you don't have it and validate your domain)

Using **[Canonical Link Tag](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/canonical-link-tag/)** in your `<head>` section, so *other* search engines also know your preferences:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/" />
```

Adding **Redirect** in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Webmaster-Tools by google: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/. Confirm you're website and somewhere there is an option to it.